# COVID-19 Vaccine: State Distribution plans versus Federal Distribution Plans

Tags: united-states, covid-19, vaccine, hhs

[HHS 10/16/2020](https://www.hhs.gov/about/news/2020/10/16/trump-aministration-partners-cvs-walgreens-provide-covid-19-vaccine-protect-vulnerable-americans-long-term-care-facilities-nationwide.html)

> To meet the Trump Administration's Operation Warp Speed (OWS) goals, the U.S. Department of Health and Human Services (HHS) and Department of Defense  today announced agreements with CVS and Walgreens to provide and administer COVID-19 vaccines to residents of long-term care facilities (LTCF) nationwide....

I just finished reading the Ohio COVID-19 Vaccination plan [Ohio Dept of Health](https://coronavirus.ohio.gov/static/docs/Interim-Draft-COVID-Vaccination-Plan-10-16-20.pdf) wherein Ohio says that they (Ohio) will be determining who will be able to administer COVID-19 Vaccines (including LTCF facilities).

As I understand it each state was required to submit their plan for their jurisdiction in mid-October, a quick glance at those state plans appears that each state is responsible for their own residents.

OTOH, the Federal Warp Speed press releases give the appearance that the Federal government is responsible for distribution and administration.

**Who is actually in charge and responsible for the distribution and administration of this vaccine, the Federal government or each of the states?**

Answer (score 3):

> Who is actually in charge and responsible for the distribution and administration of this vaccine, the Federal government or each of the states?

In the case of long-term care facilities, the federal government with fallback to the states, apparently.

[COVID-19 Vaccination Plan OHIO](https://coronavirus.ohio.gov/static/docs/Interim-Draft-COVID-Vaccination-Plan-10-16-20.pdf#page=21)

> Ohio expects that as the above actions are occurring, **the vaccine will be shipped by the federal government directly to pharmacy chains who will then vaccinate patients and perhaps staff in long-term care facilities**. However, recent guidance from the CDC indicates that the timing of this may be in question. If pharmacies are not included as administration sites for CDC direct shipments, Ohio will determine the best way to reach Ohioans who may not easily be able to access regional/hub--based administration sites through redistribution efforts based on Ohio capabilities and needs. [Emboldening added]

The following image, from an undated HHS document *From the Factory to the Frontlines*, shows an overview of the intended distribution and administration. Note that the right side of the image distinguishes between federal and state responsibilities.

[image: Overview of Distribution and Administration]
[Source](https://www.hhs.gov/sites/default/files/strategy-for-distributing-covid-19-vaccine.pdf#page=8)